# How to initialize Hibernate entities fetched by a remote method call?

Tags: java, hibernate, remoting, rmi

When calling a remote service (e.g. over RMI) to load a list of entities from a database using Hibernate, how do you manage it to initialize all the fields and references the client needs?

Example: The client calls a remote method to load all customers. With each customer the client wants the reference to the customer's list of bought articles to be initialized.

I can imagine the following solutions:

1. Write a remote method for each special query, which initializes the required fields 
   (e.g. Hibernate.initialize()) and returns the domain objects to the client.
2. Like 1. but create DTOs
3. Split the query up into multiple queries, e.g. one for the customers, a second for the customers' articles, and let the client manage the results
4. The remote method takes a DetachedCriteria, which is created by the client and executed by the server
5. Develop a custom "Preload-Pattern", i.e. a way for the client to specify explicitly which properties to preload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used 1 in the past and it worked well.

Answer (score 1):

I think number 5 is why there is a "fetch" clause in HQL. Could you use that or is the problem more complex?

Comment: this type of eager fetching is limited for some kinds of queries

Answer (score 1):

I've been at a customer who standardised its' projects on #5 and it worked really well.
The final argument of a service call was a comma-separated list of all properties to be loaded, for example:

```
CustomerService.getCustomerById(id, "parent, address, address.city")
```

I believe they used the fetch clause for this. 
I implemented the same idea once for jpa using PropertyUtils to trigger the lazy loading.

Answer (score 0):

This remote service... is it another part of the same application? if so, there's no problem sharing classes and sending instances back and forth (same goes for RMI, using stubs).

Then there's the option of accessing a web-service or something similar, where the two applications communicating share no classes, and this makes things even trickier. I'm about to face this problem in the near future, and I'll be very interested to know the answer.

Anyway, my vote is for DTOs. I think they provide the best and easiest solution, where applicable, and help keep the code simple and maintainable.

Yuval =8-)

Answer (score 0):

If your remote service only exists to provide your client with data, then switching off lazy loading on all the Hibernate entities might help.

Personally, however, I think DTOs are the right way to go. By expressing your remote interface in terms of DTOs you are sure that you get everything you need, and nothing you did not expect.